# Serving static files without directory browsing using Unfiltered and Jetty

Tags: scala, jetty, unfiltered

How can I have unfiltered-jetty serve static files without allowing directory browsing?

Jetty has the dirAllowed setting, but it does not seem easily accessible from Unfiltered.

Comment: There is no well known product or configuration called "Unfiltered Jetty".  Can you expand on this?  Where did you get this?  What version of Jetty? What product is this "Unfiltered Jetty" within?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt See the Unfiltered tag on this question - it's a minimalistic web framework. unfiltered-jetty is one of the Unfiltered modules. It uses Jetty to handle HTTP requests. See http://unfiltered.databinder.net/

Comment: Still not well known, with 14 questions and 4 people following it.  The website you pointed to makes it seem that this toolkit hides nearly everything about Jetty from you, including the ability to configure the basics of Jetty.  Would recommend filing a bug with that project for access to the configuration bits of Jetty itself.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Yeah, probably a good idea. I was asking in the hope of finding out whether I'm just not seeing how to do it, or if it is actually as difficult as it appears to me. I agree it's not the most well known tool, but I don't think that means questions about it deserve a downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working with Unfiltered 0.8.4 which uses Jetty 8:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.{HandlerCollection,ContextHandler}
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler

  def disableDirBrowsing(hc: Array[Handler]) {
    hc.map { h =>
      h match {
        case nested: HandlerCollection => disableDirBrowsing(nested.getHandlers)
        case c: ContextHandler =>
          c.setInitParameter("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.dirAllowed", "false")
        case _ => // ignore everything else
      }
    }
  }
```

If `srv` is your Unfiltered server object **after** adding contexts to it, you can now disable directory browsing like so:

```
disableDirBrowsing(srv.underlying.getHandlers)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer but I bet you can put it together by looking in 2 places:
1. the val unfiltered.jetty.Server.underlying of type org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server in the unfiltered-jetty code
2. ['Configuring a File Server'](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty#Configuring_a_File_Server) in the Jetty 8(i think) wiki. Maybe that resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(true) call?

Comment: Thanks. I was trying something like that, it just took me a long time to get it right. But I finally did! See my answer posted here.